# How to check if the current time is between two times using momentjs

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

What I tried to do:

```
  getOpenStatus = (restaurant: _Restaurant) => {
    const closeHour = moment(restaurant.close_at, "HH:mm A").hours();
    const closeMin = moment(restaurant.close_at, "HH:mm A").minutes();
    const openHour = moment(restaurant.open_at, "HH:mm A").hours();
    const openMin = moment(restaurant.open_at, "HH:mm A").minutes();
    const closeMoment = moment({ hours: closeHour, minutes: closeMin });
    const openMoment = moment({ hours: openHour, minutes: openMin });
    return moment().isAfter(openMoment) && moment().isBefore(closeMoment);
  }
```

let suppose the current time is 4:00 pm

open @ 10:30 am and close @ 11:30 pm

in this case work perfectly because the times are in the same date.

But what if the restaurant open 23 hours:

open @ 10:30 am and close @ 9:30 am

So how to handle that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
getOpenStatus = (restaurant: _Restaurant) => {
    const closeHour = moment(restaurant.close_at, "HH:mm A").hours();
    const closeMin = moment(restaurant.close_at, "HH:mm A").minutes();
    const openHour = moment(restaurant.open_at, "HH:mm A").hours();
    const openMin = moment(restaurant.open_at, "HH:mm A").minutes();
    const closeMoment = moment({ hours: closeHour, minutes: closeMin });
    const openMoment = moment({ hours: openHour, minutes: openMin });

    if (closeMoment.isBefore(openMoment)) {
        if (moment().isAfter(closeMoment)) closeMoment.add(1, "days");
        else openMoment.subtract(1, "days");
    }

    return moment().isAfter(openMoment) && moment().isBefore(closeMoment);
}
```

Comment: that is not work for the following case: current 5:41pm close: 7:00 pm and open: 11:49pm